# Simple PHP array search

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => stories
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => users
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This array is stored in a variable called `$fql`. I want to access the results with the name `stories`. I could just do:

`$stories = $fql['0']['results']`

However, it seems a bit odd selecting the array by an index number and not the name of the array.

Is there any other way I can access the results in the array alongside `[name] => stories`?

Comment: How is this array being generated?  Is this coming from another system or are you building it yourself?

Comment: It's coming from a Facebook FQL multiquery - http://hastebin.com/jibileqohi.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($fql as $arr) {
    $$arr['name'] = $arr['results'];
}
```

This will put the results into two variables, `$stories` and `$users`;

Comment: Hmm, this would work but I don't have control over the structure of the array.

Comment: Oh ok, well you could use a `foreach` and variable variables to assign the correct arrays to `$stories` and `$users` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not certain the array with `[name] => stories` will always be on index `0`, you can use a loop to find it:

```
foreach($fql as $arr) {
   if($arr['name'] == 'stories') {
      // do stuff and break;
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that stories will always be the first element, you could write a function to iterate over the array:

```
function getValuesFor($term, $list) {
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        if ($item['name'] === $term) {
            return $item['results'];
        }
    }
    return array();
}
$results = getValuesFor('stories', $array);
```